# Java - How to tell if user has entered text in a text field, but is now idle?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

For a program I am writing, I need to be able to tell if the user has entered text in a text field (but is not currently typing). I have an action listener for the text field that is able to tell whether the user is currently typing via a KeyListener, but is there a way that I can tell if the user has stopped typing but has entered text in the text box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and regularly check if it was some time since the last key press in the field.

E.g. for every key press, save a timestamp in a variable. Set the timer to check if the timestamp is older than e.g. 10 seconds.

Comment: No need keep track of a timestamp. Just restart the timer every time the Document is changed. If the timer fires, then you know the Document has changed within your specified time period and you can perform some action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You may have to attach a simple Thread that runs in the background to keep polling or you can also make use of [timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) in swing

Answer (score 0):

check the number of letters in the textfield at the event. If it is greater than 0, then the user has entered text. also when you listen to the keylistner, take a timestamp of it. and see if it is older than somethinglike 3 seconds, then the user is idle. you will mostly need a thread to watch the time. Swing Timers are mainly for GUI related functionality. So if you are using this on an IM Server, you should use normal general purpose timers.